# JQUERY - Make both elements of a select-slider show

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, select, jquery-mobile, slider

I was developing an app for a client and he asked me to make both the elements of a select (with data-role="slider") show, so that users know what the options are.

The ideal would be to change them to radio buttons, but I wanted to know if there is a way to use select, so that I haven't got to change all my code :)

```
<label for="opzioni_aggiornamentoAutomatico">Aggiornamento automatico</label>
            <select name="opzioni_aggiornamentoAutomatico" id="opzioni_aggiornamentoAutomatico" data-role="slider" data-theme="a">
                <option value="no">No</option>
                <option value="yes">Si</option>
            </select>
```

This is the code :)

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: That is not the functionality of the switch you are using: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/forms/switch/ Maybe a radio group would be better? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/forms/radiobuttons/

Comment: I agree with @PhillPafford. Use a group of radiobuttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not the functionality of the switch you are using:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/forms/switch

Maybe a radio group would be better?

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/forms/radiobuttons

Comment: Yes, the radio group would have been the best choice, but I didn't know he prefered radio buttons and didn't want to change all the code :)